# Why doesn't this String[] work in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

OK, this fails:

```
public class MyLoginBean extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

    private String[] roles;

    public MyLoginBean() {
        this.roles  = {"User"};
    }
}
```

This works:

```
public class MyLoginBean extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

    private String[] roles;

    public MyLoginBean() {
        String[] blah  = {"User"};
    }
}
```

Any information would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
public class MyLoginBean extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

    private String[] roles;

    public MyLoginBean() {
        this.roles  = new String[]{"User"};
    }
}
```

the array initializer of type `String[] foo = {"bar1", "bar2"};` can be used if only you have the declaration and initialization together. If you seperate the initialization from declaration, you cannot do `{...}`; you'll have to `new String[]{...}`

Comment: +1.  Thanks.  I accepted this because it made the most sense and you set the `roles` inside a constructor or method...which I prefer.  Thanks everyone for educating me in Java

Comment: I follow your answers. Great job. Do you blog? Please share the url if you do. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Array initializers](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#11358) (the bit in braces) are only available at the point where you're *declaring* an array variable, or as part of an [array creation expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#46168) of the form `new ElementType[] initializer`.

So this is fine:

```
// Variable declaration
String[] x = { "Blah" };
```

This isn't, because you have neither a declaration nor an array creation expression:

```
x = { "Blah" };
```

but this is fine again, as it's got an array creation expression:

```
x = new String[] { "Blah" };
```

The links above are to the relevant bits of the language specification.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put is as :

```
private String [] roles  = {"User"};  // Only allowed at the time of declaration.
```

Comment: +1 but I prefer not to set objects outside of constructors or methods.

Answer (score 0):

roles array does not have memory allocated by simply declaring it.

private String[] roles = new String[1];  // if you know only one element

public MyLoginBean() {
     String[] blah  = {"User"};

or

private String[] roles;

public MyLoginBean() {
     String[] blah  = new String[] {"User"};